# Как сделать чтобы пользователь вводил 10^-2, 10^-3 а не 0.001. При вводе 10^-2 то сразу ошибка а когда 0.01 то все ок

Tags: pascal

Вот собственно код

```
program Epsilon;
var
  e: real; {Переменная для хранения значения точности}
  k: integer; { Переменная для хранения значения аргумента}
  s: real;   { Переменная для хранения значения члена ряда}
  sum: real;   { Переменная для хранения значения суммы}

begin
  write('Введите значение точности вычислений: ');
  Readln(e);
  sum:= 0; {Начальные установки переменных}
  k:= 1;
  s:= 1/2;   
  while e < s do
    begin
      sum:= sum + s; {Вычисление суммы}
      inc(k);             {Приращение аргумента}
      s:= 1/exp(k*ln(2)); {Вычисление значения члена ряда}
    end;
  writeln('Сумма: ', sum:0:4);
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Читать ввод пользователя как строку, а потом самому её разбирать и приводить к требуемому значению. Либо просто просить ввести точность в виде количества знаков после запятой (2, 3 и т.п.), а потом делать `e := power(10, -e);`

Comment: Не совсем понял как это будет реализовано в коде

Comment: Первый вариант - длинно и сложно, второй - я написал. Просите ввести количество знаков для точности (степень), читаете их в `e`, потом делаете как я написал выше. Т.е. если вам нужна точность `10^-3`, то вы вводите `3`. Единственное - я не знаю что за pascal и есть ли в нём функция power() или в каком она модуле.

Comment: Можно вводить 1e-2, 1e-3.

Comment: О, точно, я и забыл про это :)

Comment: Я остановился на варианте 1e-2
Думаю так будет проще))
Всем спасибо))